# Are Omnifaces combined resources also minified?

Tags: minify, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

PageSpeed Insights shows me that my two combined files of **minified** resources (CSS and javascript) could be also minified. 
In CSS case I could spare 6% (2.3 KB). It's not so much but I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CombinedResourceHandler` doesn't minify resources. It only combines resources.

Minification is a relatively expensive process and is therefore usually done during build only, not during every request. There are several minification tools out, such as [YUI compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/), which is used in among others this [Minify Maven Plugin](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin).

Comment: In the CSS case, there are 5 or 6 already compressed CSS files with the last version of YUI compressor. The combined file of them with the CombinedResourceHandler need to be reduced. Why?

Comment: Apparently PageSpeed has detected some overlap in CSS selectors? There's really nothing the `CombinedResourceHandler` could do for you. It basically just streams the individual resources unmodified sequentially into a single HTTP response, each separated by a newline. It's very unlikely that those newlines account for 6%.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I'll check my files again and post later on.

Comment: I had a deeper look at the combined CSS files. Primefaces ships automatically a CSS file "theme.css", in my case Aristo. Unfortunately the file is not minified properly. I minified it with YUI and it's 4.7 KB smaller!

Comment: Actually it ships also jQuery UI CSS, which is also 4.4KB bigger than the minified one. For Aristo there is a way to use a custom theme but for jQuery I don't know right now?

Comment: OK, just to close this thread, here is my solution: I just opened the primefaces jar file and replaced the 2 CSS files with my own minified files. It works fine, pagespeed is not complaining any more.